# How to convert Date like "2012-12-26" to "december 26, 2012" in iOS ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to convert date `2012-12-26` to `december 26, 2012` in iOS?

I am using websrvice and the data comes in this format `1990-12-26`.

I want to change this to `december 26, 2012` format.

This is what I am  doing:

```
lbl_Rightside.text = [rootElement stringValueForNode:@"date"];
NSLog(@"lbl_Rightside is %@",lbl_Rightside.text);
[lbl_Rightside release];
```

Getting date to this label on `1990-12-26`. Now I want to change date to `december 26, 2012` format.

Any hints from experts would be very welcome.

Comment: there are loads of identical like questions around. Check them out before you ask.

Comment: -1 for not searching properly and asking duplicate question. please read [**FAQs**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking a question.

Comment: Close this question... I can't as reached limit :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do this kind of things. First

1. convert your date String to a date object using dateFromString:
   method.
2. from date convert to string you want using stringFromDate: method
3. Different format strings can be found [here](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/).

   ```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
   NSDate *orignalDate   =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:YOUR_ORIGINAL_STRING];

   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
    NSString *finalString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:orignalDate];

   [dateFormatter release]; //if not using ARC
   ```

Comment: I would like to suggest not to use date format for creating the string from the date. Since many different culture settings have different ways of presenting date you might want to use the `NSDateFormatterStyle` from the date or time style. This will make sure that the date is presented in the correct way that reflects the users settings.

Comment: You are telling about the string from date part right? I know what you are saying, but in the question OP especially asked for MMMM dd, yyyy format, so in that case this code works everywhere.. But your suggestion is right

Comment: True that is why is suggested it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the official Apple documentation about [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html). You should use this class to do this kind of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

by using `NSDateFormatter`

**NSString to NSDate**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];
```

**NSDate convert to NSString:**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [**NSDateFormatter**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003643) Class,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];  // this is your input date format
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];//converting string to date object
```

The format you are looking for is something like:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyy"]; // setting new format
NSLog(@"The date is = %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate])
```