# How to Convert date format from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:sss to EEE dd MMM, yyyy, hh:mm:ss in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting a date string in format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:sss` say (11/28/2014 10:21:33:940) from webservice (not from my local machine time) and I have to convert it to this format `Fri 28 NOV 2014 10:21:33:940` and display in UI in `iOS` . Can any one help me in getting this format, Thanks in advance

Comment: what's issue you occur? you have already NSDateFormatter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Date like "2012-12-26" to "december 26, 2012" in iOS ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066854/how-to-convert-date-like-2012-12-26-to-december-26-2012-in-ios)

Comment: The formats in the referenced link might be different, but it's the same process.

Comment: Are you sure your original date (the one you're trying to convert) is not `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one , it's work fine for me .

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4]; // 10.4+ style
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:sss"];
 NSString *dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

 NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM, yyyy, HH:mm:ss:sss"];
 NSString *newFormatedDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tempDate];
 NSLog(@"newFormatedDateStr is :%@",newFormatedDateStr);

//It's give -> newFormatedDateStr is :Fri 28 Nov, 2014, 11:47:32:032
```

**Update:**

```
NSString *myDateString1=@"11/28/2014 11:46:33.310";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS";//"SSS" is for milliseconds.
NSDate* DATE = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString1];

NSLog(@"%@", DATE);
```

for more detail: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

happy coding ..:)

Comment: Great Working for me. (y)

Comment: Pradip: when i executed the edited code it gives  newFormatedDateStr is :(null) and date object tempDate also is null

Comment: @NaveenKumarM Hey check now edited one

Comment: Dhaval: instead of using current date from system [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] i need to use a string "11/28/2014 11:46:33:648" I need to convert this string to EEE dd MMM, yyyy, HH:mm:ss:sss this format. So what change I have to make

Comment: @Dhaval: I need microsecond also to be displayed in UI. Thats were I getting struggling for getting that output

Comment: CHECK NOW @NaveenKumarM

Comment: @Dhaval: Thanks a lot. Now I got the Output